# Using multiple Deferred and Promises - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an page which uses jQuery 1.11.1 and is already using Deferred and Promises.

The page does approx 13 separate ajax calls and then populates a series of radio buttons into a table. Because the ajax calls will not necessarily complete in the order defined in the table, I have implemented the following. This works:

```
function getSubscriptionTypes(st_id) {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        if(st_id){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addUser.php",
                data: { st_id: st_id },
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(p) {
                d.resolve(p);
            }).fail(d.reject);
            return d.promise();
        } 
    }

    function loadSubscriptionTypes() {
        $('.subsList').each(function() {
            var st_id = $(this).closest("tr").data('stId');
            var st_id = String(st_id);
            var sub_types = getSubscriptionTypes(st_id).done(function(c){

                $.each(c, function(k,v) {
                    $('#stid-'+st_id).append('<input type="radio" value="' + v.ut_id + '-' + st_id + '" data-st-id="' + st_id + '" name="stid[' + st_id + ']"> ' + v.type + ' &nbsp;');
                });
            });
        });
    }

    loadSubscriptionTypes();
```

I'm struggling to now do the following - *after* all the radio buttons have been appended to my table, I want to use jQuery to target them (to pre-select certain ones). I'm not sure how to do this, but imagined it's a case of using *another* Deferred / Promise?

So I've tried modifying the code to this:

```
function loadSubscriptionTypes() {
    var deferredObject = $.Deferred();

    // Existing code above

    deferredObject.resolve(); 
    return deferredObject.promise();
}

var promise = loadSubscriptionTypes();

promise.done(function () {
    console.log("loadSubscriptionTypes() done");
});
```

When the page is loaded the text "loadSubscriptionTypes() done" appears in my console *before* all of the ajax calls have been completed.

Essentially, I don't know how to tell it to wait until all of the work in `loadSubscriptionTypes()` has been done, before doing other tasks.

Please can someone offer advice or point me in the right direction?

PS - I'm aware that there may be better ways of writing the code I have, but this has been put together using what I've been able to find/learn so far, and for loading the correct radio buttons into the table, actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that `getSubscriptionTypes` actually returns a Promise.  There's no need to create your own `$.Deferred` therein - doing so is a *promise antipattern*:

```
function getSubscriptionTypes(st_id) {
    return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addUser.php",
            data: { st_id: st_id },
            dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Then, in your `loadSubscriptionTypes` function, accumulate all of the returned promises into an array:

```
var promise = getSubscriptionTypes(st_id);
push(myArray, promise);
promise.done(function(c) {
    $.each(c, function(k,v) {
        ...
    });
});
```

After the outer loop, use `$.when` to wait for all of those promises to be resolved:

```
$.when.apply($, myArray).then( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and follow this through. I'm not sure what you mean by a "promise antipattern". The tutorial I followed is http://www.vasanthk.com/jquery-promises-and-deferred-objects/ and there they are making a `$.Deferred();`, resolving it (`deferredObject.resolve()`), and then returning a promise `return deferredObject.promise();`. If you search for "function testAsyncDeferred()" on that page you'll see the bit I mean. I'm not sure if that documentation is wrong, or doesn't apply to my situation?

Comment: That only applies when you're calling functions that don't already return a promise.  `$.ajax` does, so there's no need.  See "The forgotten promise" in http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

Comment: I can't use `myArray.push( getSubscriptionTypes(st_id) ... )` because when I implement that, the radio buttons don't get appended to the table. I've no idea why, but it doesn't work. I'm not convinced what I'm trying to do is even possible - all the examples I've seen online use fewer functions or simpler code.

Comment: @Andy what you're trying to do is perfectly possible.  Easy, even.   You'll still need your existing `.done` callback to be applied for each AJAX result, though.

Comment: Where does the `.done` bit go? I can't use `myArray.push(getSubscriptionTypes(st_id)).done(function(c) {` .... The rest of it does appear to be working, I just don't know where that `.done` bit can go. It has to be somewhere inside `$('.subsList').each` otherwise this won't work, because it refers to `var st_id` inside that loop.

Comment: Thanks. This works but I made an edit `myArray.push(promise);` as otherwise it has a console error "push is undefined"